# Kubuntu upgrade to 18.04 from 17.04 brings "double trouble"

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04

So as the title suggests, I have two problems, one that brought to another one, specifically. Today I managed to upgrade my Kubuntu 17.10 to 18.04. All good until I had to restart. After that, of course, after the kubuntu logo, blinking pointer to the left of the screen that after a while freezes. I tried to reinstall plasma, check on sddm, restart it, many other things that failed. So I also tried to reinstall the nvidia drivers, since at some point in the past they caused me this sort of problem, and anyway I was running out of options. And so I first purged the nvidia drivers and then my laptop froze so I had to restart. After this, I ran into the other "trouble", namely I couldn't see my wifi interface. I also tried tethering, but it doesn't recognize it either.

Comment: If you've backed up your data, try a Live USB and then, if that works, do a clean installation.

Comment: I'd rather not be forced to reinstall at this point, since I do not have a recent backup.

Comment: Which problem are you asking for help with?

Comment: Well, technically both, but priority goes to the wifi problem, since otherwise I have no internet.